# rasm and gdb wrong instruction disassemble

Tags: assembly, gdb, ida, opcode, radare2

What is instruction of the following opcode?

```
81 3E 38 43 55 AA 5A 5A
```

I checked these opcodes in sandphile

```
81 is CMP opcode 
3E is DS segment register override prefix
43 38 is offset
55 AA 5A 5A is operand
```

According to sandpile I should get such result:

```
cmp [0x4338], 0x55AA5A5A
```

and final interpreted instruction:

```
cmp [0x4338], 0x55AA5A5A
```

But when I checked with rasm and gdb, I got wrong result like that:

```
rasm2 -a x86 -b 32 -d "81 3E 38 43 55 AA 5A 5A"
cmp dword [esi], 0xaa554338
pop edx
pop edx
```

with gdb

```
x/i 0x5555567da960
   0x5555567da960:  cmpl   $0xaa554338,(%rsi)
```

Answer (score 2):

`3E` is segment override **prefix** meaning it should be at the **start** for it to be a prefix. Because it follows the opcode, it's a modr/m byte instead, and thus means `[esi]` and opcode extension `/7` which is `imm32`. So this is a `cmp [esi], imm32` instruction.

For further information see *Figure 2-1. Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Instruction Format* and the whole *CHAPTER 2 INSTRUCTION FORMAT* in the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*.

PS: You should specify what mode you are using, 16, 32 or 64 bits.